# How to make a simple Neo4J graph from a single CSV.file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to learn Neo4J and have completed a couple of tutorials. It works okay when I want to merge data from different .csv files. However in my problem I only have a single .csv file:

```
Employee, Leader
E1, L1
E2, L1
E4, L2
L1, L3
```

I want to get a graph like:
[image]

Where I get the whole structure of the whole employee-leader relationship
I know how to import a file:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///org.csv' AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
RETURN row
```

and I guess i need something like

```
MATCH row.Employee->row.Leader
```

Comment: So there are some questions to consider...are employees and leaders the same node type? Is what differentiates an employee from a leader just in their relationship, or something more intrinsic? From that, what labels should you be using? What relationships are you expecting to create? Are the nodes created already or do you have to create them first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to decide on what the labels of your nodes will be and the relationship type but this example should get you started.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///org.csv' AS row
MERGE (e:Person {id:row.Employee})
MERGE (l:Person {id:row.Leader})
MERGE (e)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(l)
```